# Return statement also ending parent method?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java programming and I was wondering if there was some kind of way for a method to also end its parent method with some sort of "super" return statement.

Ex:

```
public class test {

    public method1 () {
        ...some code...

        if (someValue == someValue2) {return;}

        ...more code...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...some code...

        method1();

        ...more code...
    }
}
```

I would like the return statement of method1 to also end the parent method's execution (in this case the main method) without adding an if statement, based on the returned value, after method1's invocation. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  You could do some grim things with exceptions, but that would be grim.

Comment: `throw new ThreadDeath()`. ThreadDeath is handled special by the default uncaught exception handler, it will not print the stack trace.

Comment: Expanding on Oli's comment; needing this kind of behavior is usually indicative of a design problem.

Comment: This is a very unusual requirement.  If you really do need to alter the control flow of an invoking method's execution from within an invoked method without returning some kind of semaphor (or, worse, exception) then I would kindly suggest that, perhaps, your design may be suboptimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

However in your example, an exit would work (i.e. stop execution of everything), but if you want "more control" then make your method return a value and check that. Keep it consistent. e.g. I like to use 0=success and anything else is some kind of error code.

```
public class test {

    public int method1 () {
        ...some code...
        if (someValue == someValue2) {return -1;}
        ...more code...
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...some code...

        if (method1() == 0) {
            ...more code...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method returns to the code that invoked it when it. So, basically you are returning to the caller. You can put a boolean return to achieve your implementation :

```
public method1 () {
        ...some code...

        if (someValue == someValue2) {return false;}
        else return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...some code...

        result = method1();
        if(!result)
        return;

        ...more code...
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want the program to exit you can use `System.exit()`

Comment: Based on your logic, the `...more code...` in `method1` would never be executed.

Comment: yeah.. got that. Removing